# Extract attachment between MIME boundary markers

Tags: performance, email, groovy

I am trying to extract invoice which is surrounded between a boundary keyword in groovy, in the below example boudary key word is `a92720f5836d4daaa4251e805cba228b` and I tried extracting the invoice between the boundary and elimated the `Content-Type` line

```
String BOUNDARY = "boundary"
def file = '''MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Wed, 17 May 2017 20:59:57 +2
Content-Type: multipart/signed; protocol="application/pkcs7-signature"; micalg="SHA256"; boundary="a92720f5836d4daaa4251e805cba228b"


--a92720f5836d4daaa4251e805cba228b
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

LEDES98BI V2[]
INVOICE_DATE|INVOICE_NUMBER|CLIENT_ID|LAW_FIRM_MATTER_ID|INVOICE_TOTAL|BILLING_START_DATE|BILLING_END_DATE|INVOICE_DESCRIPTION|LINE_ITEM_NUMBER|EXP/FEE/INV_ADJ_TYPE|LINE_ITEM_NUMBER_OF_UNITS|LINE_ITEM_ADJUSTMENT_AMOUNT|LINE_ITEM_TOTAL|LINE_ITEM_DATE|LINE_ITEM_TASK_CODE|LINE_ITEM_EXPENSE_CODE|LINE_ITEM_ACTIVITY_CODE|TIMEKEEPER_ID|LINE_ITEM_DESCRIPTION|LAW_FIRM_ID|LINE_ITEM_UNIT_COST|TIMEKEEPER_NAME|TIMEKEEPER_CLASSIFICATION|CLIENT_MATTER_ID|PO_NUMBER|CLIENT_TAX_ID|MATTER_NAME|INVOICE_TAX_TOTAL|INVOICE_NET_TOTAL|INVOICE_CURRENCY|TIMEKEEPER_LAST_NAME|TIMEKEEPER_FIRST_NAME|ACCOUNT_TYPE|LAW_FIRM_NAME|LAW_FIRM_ADDRESS_1|LAW_FIRM_ADDRESS_2|LAW_FIRM_CITY|LAW_FIRM_STATEorREGION|LAW_FIRM_POSTCODE|LAW_FIRM_COUNTRY|CLIENT_NAME|CLIENT_ADDRESS_1|CLIENT_ADDRESS_2|CLIENT_CITY|CLIENT_STATEorREGION|CLIENT_POSTCODE|CLIENT_COUNTRY|LINE_ITEM_TAX_RATE|LINE_ITEM_TAX_TOTAL|LINE_ITEM_TAX_TYPE|INVOICE_REPORTED_TAX_TOTAL|INVOICE_TAX_CURRENCY[]
19990225|96542|00711|0528|1684.45|19990101|19990131|For services rendered|1|F|2.00|-70|630|19990115|L510||A102|22547|Research Attorney's fees, Set off claim|24-6437381|350|Arnsley, Robert|PARTNR|423-987|77654|76-1235|Merten Merger|694.20|22240.25|GBP|Arnsley|Robert|O|||||||||||||||.16|100.80|VAT|100.80|[]
19990225|96542|00711|0528|1684.45|19990101|19990131|For services rendered|2|F|2.00|0|700|19990115|L510||A102|22547|Research attorney's fees, Trial pleading|24-6437381|350|Arnsley, Robert|PARTNR|423-987|77654|76-1235|Merten Merger|694.20|2240.25|GBP|Arnsley|Robert|O|||||||||||||||.16|112.00|VAT|112.00|[]
19990225|96542|00711|0528|1684.45|19990101|19990131|For services rendered|3|F|0.200|0|40|19990116|L510||A107|45875|Telephone conference with John Doe|24-6437381|200|Beaster, John|ASSOC|423-987|77654|76-1235|Merten Merger|694.20|2240.25|GBP|Beaster|John|O|||||||||||||||.16|6.40|VAT|6.40|[]
--a92720f5836d4daaa4251e805cba228b'''
def boundaryline = file.split( '\n' ).find{it.contains( 'boundary' ) }
def boundary = boundaryline.substring(boundaryline.indexOf(BOUNDARY) + BOUNDARY.length()+1).replaceAll('"','')

def invoice = file.split("--"+boundary)[1] // find inovoice between boundary string
def lines = invoice.trim().split('\\[]')
def headerLine = lines[0].trim().split('\n') //eleminating content type from header line
def header = headerLine[headerLine.length-1]
lines[0] = header //assigning header to first index
println lines
```

I am getting the expected output as below

```
[LEDES98BI V2, 
INVOICE_DATE|INVOICE_NUMBER|CLIENT_ID|LAW_FIRM_MATTER_ID|INVOICE_TOTAL|BILLING_START_DATE|BILLING_END_DATE|INVOICE_DESCRIPTION|LINE_ITEM_NUMBER|EXP/FEE/INV_ADJ_TYPE|LINE_ITEM_NUMBER_OF_UNITS|LINE_ITEM_ADJUSTMENT_AMOUNT|LINE_ITEM_TOTAL|LINE_ITEM_DATE|LINE_ITEM_TASK_CODE|LINE_ITEM_EXPENSE_CODE|LINE_ITEM_ACTIVITY_CODE|TIMEKEEPER_ID|LINE_ITEM_DESCRIPTION|LAW_FIRM_ID|LINE_ITEM_UNIT_COST|TIMEKEEPER_NAME|TIMEKEEPER_CLASSIFICATION|CLIENT_MATTER_ID|PO_NUMBER|CLIENT_TAX_ID|MATTER_NAME|INVOICE_TAX_TOTAL|INVOICE_NET_TOTAL|INVOICE_CURRENCY|TIMEKEEPER_LAST_NAME|TIMEKEEPER_FIRST_NAME|ACCOUNT_TYPE|LAW_FIRM_NAME|LAW_FIRM_ADDRESS_1|LAW_FIRM_ADDRESS_2|LAW_FIRM_CITY|LAW_FIRM_STATEorREGION|LAW_FIRM_POSTCODE|LAW_FIRM_COUNTRY|CLIENT_NAME|CLIENT_ADDRESS_1|CLIENT_ADDRESS_2|CLIENT_CITY|CLIENT_STATEorREGION|CLIENT_POSTCODE|CLIENT_COUNTRY|LINE_ITEM_TAX_RATE|LINE_ITEM_TAX_TOTAL|LINE_ITEM_TAX_TYPE|INVOICE_REPORTED_TAX_TOTAL|INVOICE_TAX_CURRENCY, 
19990225|96542|00711|0528|1684.45|19990101|19990131|For services rendered|1|F|2.00|-70|630|19990115|L510||A102|22547|Research Attorney's fees, Set off claim|24-6437381|350|Arnsley, Robert|PARTNR|423-987|77654|76-1235|Merten Merger|694.20|22240.25|GBP|Arnsley|Robert|O|||||||||||||||.16|100.80|VAT|100.80|, 
19990225|96542|00711|0528|1684.45|19990101|19990131|For services rendered|2|F|2.00|0|700|19990115|L510||A102|22547|Research attorney's fees, Trial pleading|24-6437381|350|Arnsley, Robert|PARTNR|423-987|77654|76-1235|Merten Merger|694.20|2240.25|GBP|Arnsley|Robert|O|||||||||||||||.16|112.00|VAT|112.00|, 
19990225|96542|00711|0528|1684.45|19990101|19990131|For services rendered|3|F|0.200|0|40|19990116|L510||A107|45875|Telephone conference with John Doe|24-6437381|200|Beaster, John|ASSOC|423-987|77654|76-1235|Merten Merger|694.20|2240.25|GBP|Beaster|John|O|||||||||||||||.16|6.40|VAT|6.40|]
```

My code has so many String manipulations, can it be optimized and refactored to a better version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optimization for performance is not the main concern I have with this code.  Rather, the problem is that extracting an attachment with *ad hoc* string manipulation is a fragile hack.  This is a common task and a solved problem, for which you should not reinvent the wheel — poorly.  A library — namely [JavaMail](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/) — would take into account the [relevant standards](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-5.1) and could do the job properly, even if the input varies a bit.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream
import javax.mail.Multipart
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage

def file = '''MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Wed, 17 May 2017 20:59:57 +2
Content-Type: multipart/signed; protocol="application/pkcs7-signature"; micalg="SHA256"; boundary="a92720f5836d4daaa4251e805cba228b"


--a92720f5836d4daaa4251e805cba228b
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

LEDES98BI V2[]
INVOICE_DATE|INVOICE_NUMBER|CLIENT_ID|LAW_FIRM_MATTER_ID|INVOICE_TOTAL|BILLING_START_DATE|BILLING_END_DATE|INVOICE_DESCRIPTION|LINE_ITEM_NUMBER|EXP/FEE/INV_ADJ_TYPE|LINE_ITEM_NUMBER_OF_UNITS|LINE_ITEM_ADJUSTMENT_AMOUNT|LINE_ITEM_TOTAL|LINE_ITEM_DATE|LINE_ITEM_TASK_CODE|LINE_ITEM_EXPENSE_CODE|LINE_ITEM_ACTIVITY_CODE|TIMEKEEPER_ID|LINE_ITEM_DESCRIPTION|LAW_FIRM_ID|LINE_ITEM_UNIT_COST|TIMEKEEPER_NAME|TIMEKEEPER_CLASSIFICATION|CLIENT_MATTER_ID|PO_NUMBER|CLIENT_TAX_ID|MATTER_NAME|INVOICE_TAX_TOTAL|INVOICE_NET_TOTAL|INVOICE_CURRENCY|TIMEKEEPER_LAST_NAME|TIMEKEEPER_FIRST_NAME|ACCOUNT_TYPE|LAW_FIRM_NAME|LAW_FIRM_ADDRESS_1|LAW_FIRM_ADDRESS_2|LAW_FIRM_CITY|LAW_FIRM_STATEorREGION|LAW_FIRM_POSTCODE|LAW_FIRM_COUNTRY|CLIENT_NAME|CLIENT_ADDRESS_1|CLIENT_ADDRESS_2|CLIENT_CITY|CLIENT_STATEorREGION|CLIENT_POSTCODE|CLIENT_COUNTRY|LINE_ITEM_TAX_RATE|LINE_ITEM_TAX_TOTAL|LINE_ITEM_TAX_TYPE|INVOICE_REPORTED_TAX_TOTAL|INVOICE_TAX_CURRENCY[]
19990225|96542|00711|0528|1684.45|19990101|19990131|For services rendered|1|F|2.00|-70|630|19990115|L510||A102|22547|Research Attorney's fees, Set off claim|24-6437381|350|Arnsley, Robert|PARTNR|423-987|77654|76-1235|Merten Merger|694.20|22240.25|GBP|Arnsley|Robert|O|||||||||||||||.16|100.80|VAT|100.80|[]
19990225|96542|00711|0528|1684.45|19990101|19990131|For services rendered|2|F|2.00|0|700|19990115|L510||A102|22547|Research attorney's fees, Trial pleading|24-6437381|350|Arnsley, Robert|PARTNR|423-987|77654|76-1235|Merten Merger|694.20|2240.25|GBP|Arnsley|Robert|O|||||||||||||||.16|112.00|VAT|112.00|[]
19990225|96542|00711|0528|1684.45|19990101|19990131|For services rendered|3|F|0.200|0|40|19990116|L510||A107|45875|Telephone conference with John Doe|24-6437381|200|Beaster, John|ASSOC|423-987|77654|76-1235|Merten Merger|694.20|2240.25|GBP|Beaster|John|O|||||||||||||||.16|6.40|VAT|6.40|[]
--a92720f5836d4daaa4251e805cba228b
'''
   
def inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getBytes("ASCII"))
def msg = new MimeMessage(null, inputStream)
if (msg.contentType.startsWith("multipart")) {
    Multipart mp = (Multipart)msg.content
    println mp.getBodyPart(0).content
}
```

In addition, the intent of this solution is a lot more obvious than with your slicing and dicing.

(Note that `file` needs to end with a newline, which should naturally be the case in actual usage.)

Comment: `No signature of method: javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getBodyPart() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [0]` am getting this exception with`mail-1.4.jar`

Comment: Corrected in Rev 2.

Comment: Thanks, it works in groovy, but am getting compilation error on line `mp.getBodyPart(0).getContent()` in Java, can you please provide a java version too for ` mp.getBodyPart(0).content`